# Problem with coping mmcblk0 to pc

Tags: partitions, copy-paste

I want to clone internal memory of my android phone. Version 5.0 lolipop.
I have found an tutorial website but this is not working. Web site link given below.
http://www.fciotti.com/2017/02/26/clone-android-memory

chmod +r /dev/block/mmcblk0 returns Bad mode

shell@M1:/ $ su
root@M1:/ # chmod +r /dev/block/mmcblk0
Bad mode
10|root@M1:/ #

and adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0 "mmc.img" returns

adb: error: failed to copy '/dev/block/mmcblk0' to 'mmc.img': remote Permission denied

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138153/discussion-on-question-by-animesh-das-sumit-problem-with-coping-mmcblk0-to-pc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy **mmcblk0** or **any partition** directly to pc, you need ***root*** access and ***busybox*** installed on your android phone.

Working ADB command is `adb -d shell su -c busybox dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 bs=4096 > D:\mmc.bin`

Or try these following links
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWgJdwn0-4M
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qo5lBWAIb4g

Comment: Isn't unlocked bootloader enough? (according to some other sources)